# Parse number with thousands separator

Tags: python, parsing, numbers

I want different number formats parsed properly. The strings could use commas or dots, so this is what I'd like:

```
"-1526" → -1526.0
"15 000" → 15000.0
"15.000,00" → 15000.0
"15,000.00" → 15000.0
"15,000,000" → 15000000.0
"15,000.000" → 15000.0
```

Strings like these should fail:
"157023,12.5323", "15,000,00", "15.12,000,000"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re

def parse_number(number_str):
    str = number_str.replace(" ", "")
    try:
        thousands_separator = get_thousands_separator(str)
        if thousands_separator is not None:
            str = str.replace(thousands_separator, "")
        str = str.replace(",", ".")
        parsed = float(str)
        return parsed
    except Exception:
        print(f"Invalid number format {number_str}")
    

def get_thousands_separator(str):
    match1 = re.fullmatch(r"-?\d+(?:,\d{3})*\.?\d*", str) # match 15,000,000.00
    match2 = re.fullmatch(r"-?\d+(?:\.\d{3})*,?\d*", str) # match 15.000.000,00

    if match1 is None and match2 is None:
        raise Exception(f"Invalid number format {str}")
    
    return "," if match1 is not None else "."
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built in locale library:

```
import locale

# Set your region settings: (LC_ALL means to set number and currency formats)
locale.setlocale( locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8' ) 

locale.atoi('1,000,000')
# 1000000

locale.atof('1,000,000.99')
# 1000000.99
```

Comment: Of course this doesn't help you for parsing spaces but maybe you can find a European locale where this is the standard.

Answer (score -3):

def parse_number_format(input_str):
# Supprimer tous les caractères non numériques, sauf les points et les virgules
cleaned_str = ''.join(char for char in input_str if char.isdigit() or char in ['.', ','])

```
# Remplacer les virgules par des points
cleaned_str = cleaned_str.replace(',', '.')

# Convertir en float si possible, sinon en int
try:
    return float(cleaned_str)
except ValueError:
    return 0.0
```

## Test cases

test_cases = ["-1526", "15 000", "15.000,00", "15,000.00", "15,000,000", "15,000.000",
"157023,12.5323", "15,000,00", "15.12,000,000"]

for test_case in test_cases:
result = parse_number_format(test_case)
print(f"{test_case} → {result}")

Comment: Please format your answer correctly, and write in English.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).